# How to make Eclipse autocomplete JShell methods?

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, java-9

I am trying to write a snippet of code using JShell programmatically in Eclipse, but Eclipse filters all members of `jdk.jshell.JShell` class in autocomplete. I see only members inherited from Object class. I suppose this is because that class is located in `jdk` package, but it seems like this package is exported and should be treated as public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jdk methods are filtered out by default.

The filters are set in 'Java > Appearance > Type Filters' in the Preferences. Turn off the `jdk.*` filter.